# How can I call setColorFilter in RecyclerView's custom Adapter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm creating an Android app in Kotlin that Uses a RecyclerView to display data from a Database, so I created a custom Adapter that retrieves the data from a cursor and create every Item that must be displayed on the RecyclerView.

The problem is, I need to add a color filter to a ImageView (that uses a Vector Asset to display the correspondent icon), but when I try set the color filter for the ImageView inside onBindViewHolder I get the error message:

> Expression 'colorFilter' of tupe 'ColorFilter!' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found.

I have done this in Java for other Apps and works perfectly but I kotlin doesn't work, so How can I apply a color filter in a Custom Adapter for a ReclyclerView?

This is my code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
cursor.moveToPosition(position)
val medicineType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MMDContract.columnas.TIPO_MEDICAMENTO))

when(iconsCollection?.indexOf(medicineType)){
    0 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_roundpill)}
    1 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tab)}
    2 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_capsula)}
    3 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_syrup)}
    4 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_drops)}
    5 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_eyedrops)}
    6 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ointment)}
    7 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_powder)}
    8 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_gel)}
    9 -> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_inhalator)}
    10-> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_suppository)}
    11-> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_intravenous)}
    12-> {holder.icono.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_syringe)}
}

holder.icono.colorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.context,R.color.flamingo)

holder.NombreComercial.text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MMDContract.columnas.NOMBRE_COMERCIAL_MEDICAMENTO))
holder.NombreGenerico.text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MMDContract.columnas.NOMBRE_GENERICO_MEDICAMENTO))
}
```

[image: color filter in on RecyclerView]

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
 holder.icono.setColorFilter(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MMDContract.columnas.COLOR_MEDICAMENTO)))
```